# change the Dashboard menu items label wp

Tags: dashboard

I need to change this word "Dashboard" in the top menu in wp-admin

If anyone can supply the code for the functions.php file or point me in the direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Exactly where are you looking to change the text? The admin bar on the top that shows up front and back (usually) for logged in users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [here](http://daan.kortenba.ch/rename-wp-admin-menu-items/):

```
add_filter('gettext', 'rename_admin_menu_items');
add_filter('ngettext', 'rename_admin_menu_items');

function rename_admin_menu_items( $menu ) {
 $menu = str_ireplace( 'Dashboard', 'Home', $menu );
 return $menu;
}
```

Change home to whatever you want it to be